# onhashchange not working within in-app browsers (Facebook, Twiiter)

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, twitter

I'm using the [onhashchange window event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) to detect the url hash change for [my single page webapp](http://www.jamiekdonnelly.co.uk). This enables me to fire AJAX, while retaining the browser history.

1. User clicks anchor with href="#hashlink".
2. onhashchange detects the URL updating.
3. #hashlink is extracted and passed in as AJAX url (/partials/hashlink.php).

I have discovered an issue. You may already be aware, but Facebook and Twitter have started launching external links within an in-app browser. It seems to prevent the default action of page anchors href, which has killed my hash change detection. Thus my webapp is pretty much useless :-(

The in-app browser for Facebook and Twitter were only released very recently, so finding a solution is proving to be difficult.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reason you have no upgraded to the modern HTML5 History api?

Comment: This is a good point, but the problem isn't really the history. It's the way I'm detecting the hash change to fire my AJAX. I guess I just wanted to know the reason behind it not working within these in-app browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem yesterday. Was not able to find a solution that allowed me to keep my use of hash links and the onhashchange event. I rewrote my code to use the [History API](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), which is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=session%20history%20management) (caniuse says it works for every browser except Opera Mini, but when I tested, it worked for me there, too).

Step-by-step:

1. turn all hash links into buttons, or some other accessible format (div with a role="link" attribute, etc). (don't forget to include an aria-label attribute if the buttons don't contain text clearly stating their function).

   ```
   <button class="nav__list-item" data-id="${p.websafeHandle}" aria-label="Read our Q & A with ${p.name}">
       <div class="nav__list-item__img" style="background-image: url(${p.thumbnail})"></div>
       <span class="nav__list-item__handle">${p.handle}</span>
   </button>
   ```
2. add click event listener

   ```
   const qaLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__list-item')
   qaLinks.forEach(link => {
       link.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.loadQA(e.currentTarget.dataset.id, true))
   })
   ```
3. click event handler to update page content and browser history

   ```
   loadQA(person, updateHistory) {
       // I'm condensing/summarizing the parts of my code that deal with fetching data and
       // outputting it on the page, because it's not particularly relevant to this question. 
       const data = this.data[person]
       this.container.innerHTML = template(Templates.qaPage, data.qa)

       // the loadQA function will also be called if somebody comes to this page 
       // with a hash link like the one below. in that case (on an initial visit, 
       // instead of navigation within my single-page app), I wouldn't want to add 
       // the page to the history again, thereby creating a double entry, 
       // which is why I have the updateHistory param
       if (updateHistory) {
           // update our page title and our URL and add it to the browser history
           const title = `MTI - ${data.info.name}`
           const hash = `#/qa/${data.info.websafeHandle}`
           history.pushState(null, title, hash)
       }
   }
   ```
4. event handler that will fire whenever someone uses their browser's forward/back buttons

   ```
   window.addEventListener('popstate', () => this.loadPage())
   ```
5. in the popstate event handler (which is also run on initial page load), get the URL hash and load the page accordingly

   ```
   loadPage() {
       if (!window.location.hash) {
           // the param here is for updateHistory
           this.showLanding(false)
       } else {
           const person = this.getHashParam()
           person ? this.loadQA(person, false) : this.showLanding(true)
       }
   }
   ```

Side note: I found [this app](https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/) to be really helpful for testing my local code in Facebook's IAB. You give it a link (e.g. to your dev site), it generates a link (you have to use the xip.io one to be able to open it in FB), gives you a QR code to scan with your phone, which connects your phone to its dev tools and opens that link in your browser. then you can copy the link, post it in a private FB post only you can see, and voila! you can visit your local server in the Facebook browser, and Ghostlab gives you access to all the dev tools you'd normally have in Chrome.